# How can I convert an array into a string that lists each item next to its position in the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, string-interpolation

I would like to take an array...
    `teams = ["Cowboys", "Heat", "Blue Devils"]`

...and convert this to a string...
    `# => "1. Cowboys 2. Heat 3. Blue Devils"`

...and use string interpolation to concatenate it with another string.

`# => "My three favorite teams: 1. Cowboys 2. Heat 3. Blue Devils"`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
teams = ["Cowboys", "Heat", "Blue Devils"]
numbered = teams.each_with_index.map { |team, i| "#{i + 1}. #{team}" }.join(" ")
# => "1. Cowboys 2. Heat 3. Blue Devils"
```

Then you can interpolate:

```
fave_teams = "My #{teams.size} favorite teams: #{numbered}"
```

`each_with_index` adds the position of each element and returns an enumerator that you can map over with a block. The block receives each item and its index.

Answer (score 0):

```
teams.map.with_index(1) do |t, i|
  "#{ i }. #{ t }"
end.join( ' ' )
```